# BuildRestClient import causes problems - Azure DevOps

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Currently i'm trying to get the workitems of my azure devops server with following code:

```
export function geWorkitems(target: HTMLElement): void {
    // Get an instance of the client
    let client = WorkitemRestClient.getClient();
    client.getWorkItems([1]).then(definitions => {
        target.innerText = JSON.stringify(definitions)
    }
    );
}
show("workitems", geWorkitems);
```

when I include the needed import its gives me this error:

```
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.ts(1202)
```

The import i am talking about:

```
import WorkitemRestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");
```

People have been suggesting to write it this way, but it still doesnt work

```
import WorkitemRestClient from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient";
```

same with `import BuildRestClient = require("TFS/Build/RestClient");`

Answer (score 1):

#### Best method

Have you tried the code suggested in the error message (`import {a} from "mod"`):

```
import { geWorkitems } from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient";
```

Make sure you have the correct spelling and capitalisation because the export name must be the same as the import

---

#### Alternative 1

You could also try:

```
const WorkitemRestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");
```

using require is like normal assignments so you can't use the import keyword.

require is less used nowadays and works better with the `module.exports = {}` notation

---

#### Alternative 2

Finally, you could keep the second import you mentionne:

```
import WorkitemRestClient from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient";
```

but you need to export it differently with the `default` keyword:

```
export default function geWorkitems(target: HTMLElement): void {
```

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but I still get Errors:

    error TS2307: Cannot find module 'TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient' or its corresponding type declarations.

Im lost :(

Comment: Nevermind I solved the problem with a diffrent methode: var WorkitemRestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");

Comment: It's the same as `Alternative 1` except var is not used anymore in javascript. It is a relic of the past.